# Saving date and time with datetime datatype using sqlite in WinRT 8.1: System.InvalidCastException

Tags: vb.net, datetime, sqlite, windows-runtime, type-conversion

I am trying to use date and time picker controls in WinRT 8.1 as shown:

Date picker control

[image]

Time Picker control:

[image]

Now declaring them in my table as shown:

```
Public Class mydata
        <MaxLength(5), PrimaryKey> _
        Public Property name() As String
        <MaxLength(50)> _
        Public Property date1() As DateTime
        <MaxLength(50)> _
        Public Property date2() As DateTime
End Class
```

Now I'm trying to use them as shown:

```
Dim dateFormatter As New DateTimeFormatter("shortdate")
Dim timeFormatter As New DateTimeFormatter("shorttime")

Dim selectedDate1 As DateTimeOffset = Me.selectedDate1.Date
Dim combinedate1Value As New DateTimeOffset(New Date(selectedDate1.Year, selectedDate1.Month, selectedDate1.Day) + Me.selectedDate1.Time)


Dim selectedDate2 As DateTimeOffset = Me.selectedDate2.Date
Dim combineddate2Value As New DateTimeOffset(New Date(selectedDate2.Year, selectedDate2.Month, selectedDate2.Day) + Me.selectedDate2.Time)


If CustomerName.Text <> "" Then
      Dim dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "mydata.db")
      Using db = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath)
         ' Create the tables if they don't exist
          db.Insert(New person() With {.name = CustomerName.Text.ToString(), .date1 = dateFormatter.Format(combinedate1Value) & " " & timeFormatter.Format(combinedate1Value), .date2= dateFormatter.Format(combinedate2Value) & " " & timeFormatter.Format(combinedate2Value)})

          db.Commit()
          db.Dispose()
          db.Close()
          Dim line = New MessageDialog("Records Inserted")
          Await line.ShowAsync()
      End Using
Else
      Throw New NullReferenceException("Please enter the required fields")
End If
```

Now the problem is while saving I get an exception as shown:

[image]

So an anyone let me know how do I save the dates to my table with the correct datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTimeFormatter should only be used when formatting strings to be displayed to the user. Since you are trying to format the string for a backend (database), you should be using standard formats. In addition, SQLite requires a particular format for the dates as a standard ISO8601 string ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). You should use the .Net date formatting:

```
combinedate1Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: @Eric-Thanks for your reply...That made me simple :)